# Java, Tomcat : AN invalid character was present in the cookie value

Tags: java, tomcat, cookies

I am working a SPring-MVC project where I am trying to set the cookie. I am using Tomcat7, And I have already set the cookie processor in context.xml to `Rfc6265CookieProcessor`. Currently I am getting the following error.

Error log :

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An invalid character [44] was present in the Cookie value

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An invalid character [44] was present in the Cookie value

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An invalid character [44] was present in the Cookie value
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:979)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:869)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

Cookie values to be set : The spaces are not actually there, got them while reformatting in IntelliJ to get them in one paragraph :

```
  s.d774b7c6eabba92fce3edbed8a9b003b,
s.bdf5f951e4ab858aac87fb182439f57f,
s.e77bd0cd86b4af86c4a550ec11d71d4c,
                        s.431334e112350c9d545f7a44cbcc530d,
                        s.6e6057e5483b538cf9c6daf2934fd825,
                        s.ea2438094c8631123fab3bf3efb7ec17,
                        s.e17b1d9dd1b9702ca8c9e95d30906dd5, s .3f 3 c8f3fc19597025ef87dafc0fb277a, s .5531
                b742d6e12717f4071818b5861bd2, s .420811998d
                b14d0a68dd9e3d3c04849f, s.d8ed1aa3b0a2e513d449a96182898160, s.f3b5784d6e777032c6b7576e7d824af0, s .69
                bc19557e43fcfa83816f427b60a09d, s .5677087e bc57003436c55f49fceff5cb, s .5f
                a872b3e84fd69618534940034e1adb, s.fe4184c9b925ddf04def79c0c55392ca, s .74e4438d 05f 267
                c48297a0c66a7dbeba, s .95e c071a356cf1998d809267006725db, s .9 b72a01cfda4509833c1f0c7bf2afdac, s .5240f
                10897d 2f 96f 49d 0328 a2521519c, s .518 cd1d749fbba6540424874d64c5443
```

Comment: I'm not reading that. Where's the character `0x44` in all that? Basically, you can't put that character into a cookie value: you need to encode it somehow. So, either figure out why `0x44` is ending up in your cookie value and fix that (because it's an error?) or encode your binary data using e.g. base64 before dropping it into a cookie.

Answer (score 4):

Character `44` (comma) is not valid in a cookie value.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to change the version of Tomcat, I was working with 8.5 and I was getting the character error in cookie value, I changed to Tomcat 9 and the problem continued, finally with Tomcat 7 it was solved. The most logical option is to replace the commas in the cookie values, but if you want to quickly fix the problem locally and keep working you might consider switching from Tomcat.